# Google closure compiler add file date when compiling

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I'm compiling a Javascript file using Google Closure Compiler.  I would like to insert a unique value at compile time that I could use to append to the file name of another Javascript file for a web worker.

I know you can define values through the compiler using `--define` but I'm not sure how I would do this with a dynamic value.

```
var filename = "myfile.js?" + __TIMESTAMP_OF_MYFILE_JS__
var worker = new Worker(filename);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd probably have to do something like

```
/**
 * @define {string}
 */
var COMPILATION_DATE = '';

var filename = 'myfile.js?' + COMPILATION_DATE;
```

and then (edited to add quotes -- see comments)

```
#!/bin/bash

java -jar compiler.jar --define="COMPILATION_DATE='$(date +%F)'" --js=your_file.js ...
```

Use `date --help` to figure out how to get the date formatted exactly the way you want.

Comment: Thanks for your response!  This is exactly what I'm looking for but I'm getting this error.  java.lang.RuntimeException: --define flag syntax invalid: COMPILATION_DATE=

Comment: It looks like the `$()` is not working for some reason? Maybe you need to add quotes? `--define=COMPILATION_DATE='$(date +%F)'`. If something like that doesn't work you might want to open a new question, labeled with "bash" (or whichever shell you're actually using)

Comment: Thanks for all your help!  It finally worked with multiple quotes.  `--define="COMPILATION_DATE='$(date +%F)'"`